# Swing - Issue with lists not working inside paintComponent method

Tags: java, swing, paint

I'm trying to render the positions of multiple `fighters` onscreen. The relevant code is as follows:

```
public void run() {
        double ns = 1000000000.0 / tps;
        double delta = 0;

        int frames = 0;
        int updates = 0;

        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();

        while (running) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();

            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;

            while(delta >= 1) {
                update();
                updates++;
                delta--;
            }

            frame.getContentPane().repaint();
            frames++;

            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer >= 1000) {
                timer += 1000;
                frame.setTitle(title + "  |  " + updates + " ups, " + frames + " fps");
                frames = 0;
                updates = 0;
            }
        }

        stop();
    }

    private void update() {

         if (Math.random() < .1) {

            Fighter newFighter = new Fighter();
            fighterList.add(newFighter);

        } 

    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
          super.paintComponent(g);  // paint background
          setBackground(Color.BLUE);
          System.out.println(fighterList.size());
          for (int i = 0; i<fighters; i++) {
              System.out.println("Attempted");
              g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
              g.drawRect((int) fighterList.get(i).xPos,
                      (int) fighterList.get(i).yPos,
                      fighterList.get(i).radius,
                      fighterList.get(i).radius);
              System.out.println("Rendered");
          }

       }
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game();
        game.frame.setContentPane(new Game());
        game.frame.setResizable(false);
        game.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        game.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
        game.frame.setVisible(true); 

        game.start();


    }
```

Issue is, nothing is being drawn to the screen. Additionally, running `System.out.println(fighterList.size());` gives different outputs based on where it's run - when run inside `paintComponent` it always returns zero, wheras when run inside `update` it returns the proper amount. Is this an issue with scope, or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: 1) *"The relevant code is as follows:"*  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely a synchronization issue. Your `paintComponent()` method is always called from the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) while your `run()` method runs in its own separate thread. This is where `update()` gets called which adds new `Fighter`s to the list.

You need proper synchronization so both (or all) threads will see the same consistent data.

Also since your model (data) may be modified during a repaint, you should also "clone" the model to avoid inconsistent model being painted. Or if you don't want to clone it, synchronize access to the model so it can't get modified while it is painted.